# "codeChef INTEST" not getting 1 line in solution

Tags: java

The purpose of this problem is to verify whether the method you are using to read input data is sufficiently fast to handle problems branded with the enormous Input/Output warning. You are expected to be able to process at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime.

http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST/

Input

The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=107). The next n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than 109, each.
Output

Write a single integer to output, denoting how many integers ti are divisible by k.
Example

Input:
7 3

1

51

966369

7

9

999996

11

Output:
4

And i have solution which is :-

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int ans = 0;
    int count = 0, n = 0, in = 0, data = 0;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("G://test1.txt");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    while ((in = is.read()) != ' ')

        count = count * 10 + in - '0'; // how does this line work ? 

    while ((in = is.read()) != '\n')

        n = n * 10 + in - '0';

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        in = is.read(b, 0, 1024);

        if (in == -1) {

            break;

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < in; j++) {

            if (b[j] != '\n') {

                data = data * 10 + b[j] - '0';

            } else {

                if (data % n == 0)

                    ans++;

                data = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans + "ans");
}
}
```

**count = count * 10 + in - '0'; // how does this line work ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count = count * 10 + in - '0'; This converts a character array(as a sequence of input) into its corresponding integer value. Here "in" is a character you need to subtract zero from it inorder to obtain the actual integer value corresponding to that character.

example let say u wanna parse 24

you want to parse this character sequence as a integer value

you obtain 2 from character '2' by subtracting character '0' from it

count is i.e 2

when character 4 is encountered you obtain 4 from character '4' by subtracting character '0' from it

now count becomes 2*10 + 4 = 24

Here is a clean code of mine to do the same

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
        String[] line = reader.readLine().split("\\s");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             int t = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
             if (t % k == 0) {
                 ++count;
             }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
   }
}
```